# widgets for Category choice in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I just want add a class 'form control' in category choices

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # blog_title= forms.TextInput(label='Title',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    # blog_content= forms.Textarea(label='Blog Content',widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    # blog_image= forms.ImageField(label='Blog Thambnail',widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    

    class Meta:
        model=Blog
        fields=['blog_title','category','blog_content','blog_image']
        widgets={
            'blog_title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'blog_content':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'category':forms.?
            'blog_image':forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

is there any specific input field for that?i have given a question mark there.

Comment: What type of field is category?

Comment: @lucutzu33 it's a blog project, so here is about 20-30 categories. when user writing a blog they has to chose one

Comment: You can use `forms.SelectMultiple` and `forms.ChecboxSelectMultiple` to use checkbox to show the options. Neither are especially fancy looking, so probably you'll want an external lib like select2.